# Are there any downsides of using JS_THEME group by a contrib module?

Tags: theming

I'm currently working on a contrib module with JS logic that in most cases should run last. To achieve that I'm using `drupal_add_js` with the following options:

`['scope' => 'footer', 'group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 10,]`

During the internal code review I was told that using `JS_THEME` group in a contrib module is not right, since modules should stay within their scope of `JS_DEFAULT` and leave `JS_THEME` for theme JS. Are there really any downsides of using `JS_THEME` in a contrib module?

From my perspective it is more flexible this way. If a theme developer wants to run custom JS before or after my JS code, they can easily do so with a theme JS or even with a custom module JS. However, if I'm using `JS_DEFAULT` in my module, the only way for a theme developer to run their JS code **before** mine, is to add it to `JS_DEFAULT` group as well which again is counterintuitive.